# How to align two lists of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two sorted lists of numbers `A` and `B` with `B` being at least as long as `A`.  Say:

```
A = [1.1, 2.3, 5.6, 5.7, 10.1]
B = [0, 1.9, 2.4, 2.7, 8.4, 9.1, 10.7, 11.8]
```

I want to associate each number in `A` with a different number in `B` but preserving order.  For any such mapping we define the total distance to be the sum of the squared distances between mapped numbers.

For example:

If we map 1.1 to 0 0 then 2.3 can be mapped to any number from 1.9 onwards. But if we had mapped 1.1 to 2.7, then 2.3 could only be mapped to a number in B from 8.4 onwards.

Say we map 1.1->0, 2.3->1.9, 5.6->8.4, 5.7->9.1, 10.1->10.7. This is a valid mapping and has distance (1.1^2+0.4^2+2.8^2+3.4^2+0.6^2).

Another example to show a greedy approach will not work:

```
 A = [1, 2]
 B = [0, 1, 10000]
```

If we map 1->1 then we have to map 2->10000 which is bad.

The task is to find the valid mapping with minimal total distance.

Is hard to do?  I am interested in a method that is fast when the lists are of length a few thousand.

Comment: No, it's not hard to do. Brute force will work for short lists. Dynamic programming will work for larger lists.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you give a solution for larger lists?

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, broadly.

Comment: If you assign 1.1 to 0 and 2.3 to 2.4, you're left with the sub-problem `A = [5.6,5.7,10.1] B=[2.7,8.4,...]` If you assign 1.1 to 1.9 and 2.3 to 2.4, then you are left with the same subproblem. So you can see that a sub-problem is defined by the number of elements left in A, and in B. You can apply dynamic programming by memoizing the answers to the subproblems.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/matching-error-prone-sequences-of-numbers-e-g-time-codes-to-each-other/) (minus shift estimation).

Comment: @Anush What are the typical sizes of A and B in your application? Are they of similar sizes or is A much shorter than B?

Comment: @GZ0 Their lengths are in the 1000s up to a max of about 15,000. A can be as small as 1/20 of the size of B but sometimes is of a similar length.

Comment: Do the input lists contain only non-negative integers?

Comment: @GZ0 No. The lists are sorted and only contain positive numbers.

Comment: What is the range and decimal length (precision) of the values in the input?

Comment: @גלעדברקן  We can assume the number are all less than 1,000,000 and that they have only one decimal place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And here is a `O(n)` solution! (This is the original attempt, see below for a fixed version.)

The idea is as follows.  We first solve the problem for every other element, turn that into a very close solution, then use dynamic programming to find the real solution.  This is solving a problem that is half the size first, followed by `O(n)` work.  Using the fact that `x + x/2 + x/4 + ... = 2x` this turns out to be `O(n)` work.

This very, very much requires sorted lists.  And doing a band that is 5 across is overkill, it very much looks like a band that is 3 across always gives the right answer, but I wasn't confident enough to go with that.

```
def improve_matching (list1, list2, matching):
    # We do DP forward, trying a band that is 5 across, building up our
    # answer as a linked list.  If our answer changed by no more than 1
    # anywhere, we are done.  Else we recursively improve again.
    best_j_last = -1
    last = {-1: (0.0, None)}
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        best_j = None
        best_cost = None
        this = {}
        for delta in (-2, 2, -1, 1, 0):
            j = matching[i] + delta
            # Bounds sanity checks.
            if j < 0:
                continue
            elif len(list2) <= j:
                continue

            j_prev = best_j_last
            if j <= j_prev:
                if j-1 in last:
                    j_prev = j-1
                else:
                    # Can't push back this far.
                    continue

            cost = last[j_prev][0] + (list1[i] - list2[j])**2
            this[j] = (cost, [j, last[j_prev][1]])
            if (best_j is None) or cost <= best_cost:
                best_j = j
                best_cost = cost

        best_j_last = best_j
        last = this

    (final_cost, linked_list) = last[best_j_last]
    matching_rev = []
    while linked_list is not None:
        matching_rev.append( linked_list[0])
        linked_list = linked_list[1]
    matching_new = [x for x in reversed(matching_rev)]
    for i in range(len(matching_new)):
        if 1 < abs(matching[i] - matching_new[i]):
            print "Improving further" # Does this ever happen?
            return improve_matching(list1, list2, matching_new)

    return matching_new

def match_lists (list1, list2):
    if 0 == len(list1):
        return []
    elif 1 == len(list1):
        best_j = 0
        best_cost = (list1[0] - list2[0])**2
        for j in range(1, len(list2)):
            cost = (list1[0] - list2[j])**2
            if cost < best_cost:
                best_cost = cost
                best_j = j
        return [best_j]
    elif 1 < len(list1):
        # Solve a smaller problem first.
        list1_smaller = [list1[2*i] for i in range((len(list1)+1)//2)]
        list2_smaller = [list2[2*i] for i in range((len(list2)+1)//2)]
        matching_smaller = match_lists(list1_smaller, list2_smaller)

        # Start with that matching.
        matching = [None] * len(list1)
        for i in range(len(matching_smaller)):
            matching[2*i] = 2*matching_smaller[i]

        # Fill in the holes between
        for i in range(len(matching) - 1):
            if matching[i] is None:
                best_j = matching[i-1] + 1
                best_cost = (list1[i] - list2[best_j])**2
                for j in range(best_j+1, matching[i+1]):
                    cost = (list1[i] - list2[j])**2
                    if cost < best_cost:
                        best_cost = cost
                        best_j = j
                matching[i] = best_j

        # And fill in the last one if needed
        if matching[-1] is None:
            if matching[-2] + 1 == len(list2):
                # This will be an invalid matching, but improve will fix that.
                matching[-1] = matching[-2]
            else:
                best_j = matching[-2] + 1
                best_cost = (list1[-2] - list2[best_j])**2
                for j in range(best_j+1, len(list2)):
                    cost = (list1[-1] - list2[j])**2
                    if cost < best_cost:
                        best_cost = cost
                        best_j = j
                matching[-1] = best_j

        # And now improve.
        return improve_matching(list1, list2, matching)

def best_matching (list1, list2):
    matching = match_lists(list1, list2)
    cost = 0.0
    result = []
    for i in range(len(matching)):
        pair = (list1[i], list2[matching[i]])
        result.append(pair)
        cost = cost + (pair[0] - pair[1])**2
    return (cost, result)
```

### UPDATE

There is a bug in the above.  It can be demonstrated with `match_lists([1, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3])`.  However the solution below is also `O(n)` and I believe has no bugs.  The difference is that instead of looking for a band of fixed width, I look for a band of width dynamically determined by the previous matching.  Since no more than 5 entries can look to match at any given spot, it again winds up `O(n)` for this array and a geometrically decreasing recursive call.  But long stretches of the same value cannot cause a problem.

```
def match_lists (list1, list2):
    prev_matching = []

    if 0 == len(list1):
        # Trivial match
        return prev_matching
    elif 1 < len(list1):
        # Solve a smaller problem first.
        list1_smaller = [list1[2*i] for i in range((len(list1)+1)//2)]
        list2_smaller = [list2[2*i] for i in range((len(list2)+1)//2)]
        prev_matching = match_lists(list1_smaller, list2_smaller)

    best_j_last = -1
    last = {-1: (0.0, None)}
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        lowest_j = 0
        highest_j = len(list2) - 1
        if 3 < i:
            lowest_j = 2 * prev_matching[i//2 - 2]
        if i + 4 < len(list1):
            highest_j = 2 * prev_matching[i//2 + 2]

        if best_j_last == highest_j:
            # Have to push it back.
            best_j_last = best_j_last - 1

        best_cost = last[best_j_last][0] + (list1[i] - list2[highest_j])**2
        best_j = highest_j
        this = {best_j: (best_cost, [best_j, last[best_j_last][1]])}

        # Now try the others.
        for j in range(lowest_j, highest_j):
            prev_j = best_j_last
            if j <= prev_j:
                prev_j = j - 1

            if prev_j not in last:
                continue
            else:
                cost = last[prev_j][0] + (list1[i] - list2[j])**2
                this[j] = (cost, [j, last[prev_j][1]])
                if cost < best_cost:
                    best_cost = cost
                    best_j = j

        last = this
        best_j_last = best_j

    (final_cost, linked_list) = last[best_j_last]
    matching_rev = []
    while linked_list is not None:
        matching_rev.append( linked_list[0])
        linked_list = linked_list[1]
    matching_new = [x for x in reversed(matching_rev)]

    return matching_new

def best_matching (list1, list2):
    matching = match_lists(list1, list2)
    cost = 0.0
    result = []
    for i in range(len(matching)):
        pair = (list1[i], list2[matching[i]])
        result.append(pair)
        cost = cost + (pair[0] - pair[1])**2
    return (cost, result)
```

### Note

I was asked to explain why this works.

Here is my heuristic understanding.  In the algorithm we solve the half-problem.  Then we have to solve the full problem.

The question is how far can an optimal solution for the full problem be forced to be from the optimal solution to the half problem?  We push it to the right by having every element in `list2` that wasn't in the half problem be large as possible, and every element in `list1` that wasn't in the half problem be small as possible.  But if we shove the ones from the half problem to the right, and put the duplicate elements where they were then modulo boundary effects, we've got 2 optimal solutions to the half problem and nothing moved by more than to where the next element right was in the half problem.  Similar reasoning applies to trying to force the solution left.

Now let's discuss those boundary effects.  Those boundary effects are at the end by 1 element.  So when we try to shove an element off the end, we can't always.  By looking 2 elements instead of 1 over, we add enough wiggle room to account for that as well.

Hence there has to be an optimal solution that is fairly close to the half problem doubled in an obvious way.  There may be others, but there is at least one.  And the DP step will find it.

I would need to do some work to capture this intuition into a formal proof, but I'm confident that it could be done.

Comment: This is an intriguing algorithm. I look forward to understanding it more.

Comment: @Anush The idea is as follows.  Suppose that we have the best solution for the "every other element".  When we add in the ones in between as best we can, it appears that the best solution can move around by 1 element, but no more than that.  I don't have a formal proof though.  But I also haven't been able to create an array where it wasn't true.

Comment: Very interesting idea to find the optimal substructure. Not sure what happens when the optimal solution of a subproblem is non-unique though.

Comment: I just had an instance with 306 lines logged of "Improving further." I was using random.uniform(0, 100000-1) for A and (900000, 1000000-1) for B where A was 500 and B was 10000 elements. What would be the approximate complexity in an instance like that?

Comment: @GZ0 Thinking through what happens if B has the same value multiple times, I have found a bug.  I think that it is fixable though.

Comment: @גלעדברקן If you were improved multiple times, I am suspicious that it is producing bad results.  The question is why. :-(

Comment: Results were good so far. I was checking against my DP. (btw, I also tried with all (although not with only some) duplicate values and it seemed to work fine.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן I proved the bug and wrote my improvement.

Comment: @GZ0 I have verified the bug that your comment started me on the path towards.  I am more confident about the current version.

Comment: Awesome. If you have any time at all, could you please explain a reasoning that guarantees the optimal result is achievable in O(n) time?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I added an explanation for why this doubling approach should be expected to find an optimal solution.

Comment: Pretty awesome. Random trials all perfect so far.

Comment: Maybe publish a paper or something :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive solution.  Pick the middle element of `a`; map that to each possible element of `b` (leave enough on each end to accommodate the left and right sections of `a`).  For each such mapping, compute the single-element cost; then recur on each of the left and right fragments of `a` and `b`.

Here's the code; I'll leave memoization as an exercise for the student.

```
test_case = [
    [ [1, 2], [0, 1, 10] ],
    [ [1.1, 2.3, 5.6, 5.7, 10.1], [0, 1.9, 2.4, 2.7, 8.4, 9.1, 10.7, 11.8] ],
]

import math
indent = ""


def best_match(a, b):
    """
    Find the best match for elements in a mapping to b, preserving order
    """

    global indent
    indent += "  "
    # print(indent, "ENTER", a, b)

    best_cost = math.inf
    best_map = []

    if len(a) == 0:
        best_cost = 0
        best_map = []

    else:

        # Match the middle element of `a` to each eligible element of `b`
        a_midpt = len(a) // 2
        a_elem = a[a_midpt]
        l_margin = a_midpt
        r_margin = a_midpt + len(b) - len(a) 

        for b_pos in range(l_margin, r_margin+1):
            # For each match ...
            b_elem = b[b_pos]
            # print(indent, "TRACE", a_elem, b_elem)

            # ... compute the element cost ...
            mid_cost = (a_elem - b_elem)**2

            # ... and recur for similar alignments on left & right list fragments
            l_cost, l_map = best_match(a[:l_margin], b[:b_pos])
            r_cost, r_map = best_match(a[l_margin+1:], b[b_pos+1:])

            # Check total cost against best found; keep the best
            cand_cost = l_cost + mid_cost + r_cost
            # print(indent, " COST", mid_cost, l_cost, r_cost)
            if cand_cost < best_cost:
                best_cost = cand_cost
                best_map = l_map[:] + [(a_elem, b_elem)]
                best_map.extend(r_map[:])

    # print(indent, "LEAVE", best_cost, best_map)
    return best_cost, best_map


for a, b in test_case:
    print('\n', a, b)
    print(best_match(a, b))
```

Output:

```
 a = [1, 2] 
 b = [0, 1, 10]
2 [(1, 0), (2, 1)]

 a = [1.1, 2.3, 5.6, 5.7, 10.1] 
 b = [0, 1.9, 2.4, 2.7, 8.4, 9.1, 10.7, 11.8]
16.709999999999997 [(1.1, 1.9), (2.3, 2.4), (5.6, 2.7), (5.7, 8.4), (10.1, 10.7)]
```

Comment: How would this implementation fair with a list of thousands of elements as the OP suggested (since Python is has a low default recursion limit I'm guessing for a reason)? (Voted up, by the way, but also tried a bottom-up approach.)

Comment: The algorithm halves the list at each step; the recursion depth for most cases will be `len(b) - len(a)`, with memoization shortening that as the algorithm progresses.  `log(len(a))` is another factor, but will generally be less than the length difference.

Comment: I believe Python's default recursion limit is 1000. (My first [draft](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57173919/revisions) offered a slightly different, although not unexpected recursion.)

Comment: When you have a large problem that's finite bounded, you increase the recursion depth.

Comment: Sure, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: If I believe that we can show that the optimum placement of the middle gives a "U-shaped" reward function.  Meaning that it has a minimum (possibly at the end) and is increasing going either direction from there.  I keep thinking that if `B` had length `N`, a running time of something like `O(N log(n)^2)` should be doable here.

Comment: Isn't that the definition of "optimum"?

Comment: @Prune Optimum just means best.  It says nothing about the distribution of the other values.

Comment: Ah; good point.  Nothing said that the second derivative would play nicely.

Comment: I *did* ... no, I didn't.  I chopped off the last 5 lines of the code.  Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

For giggles and grins, here is what is hopefully a much faster solution than either of the other working ones.  The idea is simple.  First we do a greedy match left to right.  Then a greedy match right to left.  This gives us bounds on where each element can go.  Then we can do a DP solution left to right only looking at possible values.

If the greedy approaches agree, this will take linear time.  If the greedy approaches are very far apart, this can take quadratic time.  But the hope is that the greedy approaches produce reasonably close results, resulting in close to linear performance.

```
def match_lists(list1, list2):
    # First we try a greedy matching from left to right.
    # This gives us, for each element, the last place it could
    # be forced to match. (It could match later, for instance
    # in a run of equal values in list2.)
    match_last = []
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        while True:
            if len(list2) - j <= len(list1) - i:
                # We ran out of room.
                break
            elif abs(list2[j+1] - list1[i]) <= abs(list2[j] - list1[i]):
                # Take the better value
                j = j + 1
            else:
                break
        match_last.append(j)
        j = j + 1

    # Next we try a greedy matching from right to left.
    # This gives us, for each element, the first place it could be
    # forced to match.
    # We build it in reverse order, then reverse.
    match_first_rev = []
    j = len(list2) - 1
    for i in range(len(list1) - 1, -1, -1):
        while True:
            if j <= i:
                # We ran out of room
                break
            elif abs(list2[j-1] - list1[i]) <= abs(list2[j] - list1[i]):
                # Take the better value
                j = j - 1
            else:
                break
        match_first_rev.append(j)
        j = j - 1
    match_first = [x for x in reversed(match_first_rev)]

    # And now we do DP forward, building up our answer as a linked list.
    best_j_last = -1
    last = {-1: (0.0, None)}
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        # We initialize with the last position we could choose.
        best_j = match_last[i]
        best_cost = last[best_j_last][0] + (list1[i] - list2[best_j])**2
        this = {best_j: (best_cost, [best_j, last[best_j_last][1]])}

        # Now try the rest of the range of possibilities
        for j in range(match_first[i], match_last[i]):
            j_prev = best_j_last
            if j <= j_prev:
                j_prev = j - 1 # Push back to the last place we could match
            cost = last[j_prev][0] + (list1[i] - list2[j])**2
            this[j] = (cost, [j, last[j_prev][1]])
            if cost < best_cost:
                best_cost = cost
                best_j = j
        last = this
        best_j_last = best_j

    (final_cost, linked_list) = last[best_j_last]
    matching_rev = []
    while linked_list is not None:
        matching_rev.append(
                (list1[len(matching_rev)], list2[linked_list[0]]))
        linked_list = linked_list[1]
    matching = [x for x in reversed(matching_rev)]
    return (final_cost, matching)

print(match_lists([1.1, 2.3, 5.6, 5.7, 10.1], [0, 1.9, 2.4, 2.7, 8.4, 9.1, 10.7, 11.8]))
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to guarantee O(n log n) worst case.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I suspect not. I tried earlier based on a recursive ternary search for the optimum place to put the middle node, but failed.  However this one works in under a minute for arrays of random numbers of size 100,000 and 100,500.  In general if the arrays have size `n` and `n + O(sqrt(n))` the  running time is `O(n sqrt(n))`.  If you make the gap larger or smaller than that, running time improves.  That should be good enough.

Comment: @גלעדברקן My implementation makes heavy use of the assumption that A and B are sorted lists.  The timing code that you use produces unsorted lists.  If you can reproduce the apparent but with sorted lists, I would be interested.  That said, I did find a small bug with duplicate values in B, which I fixed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm not getting the discrepancy when the numbers are sorted. This is indeed much faster now.

Comment: In other news, I might have figured out a `O(n)` solution!  I'm not sure that it works yet.

Comment: `O(n)` seems very hard to achieve. Every distance calculation of a candidate mapping takes `O(n)`. I doubt there exists an algorithm that can limit the average number of distance calculations to `O(1)` in the worst case.

Comment: @GZ0 And yet see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209000/585411 for a `O(n)` solution that in my testing agrees with the others.

Comment: @גלעדברקן You might also want to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Python is not very friendly with recursion so attempting to apply it to a list of thousands of elements might not fair so well. Here is a bottom-up approach that takes advantage of the optimal solution for any `a` from `A` as we increase the index for its potential partner from `B` being non-decreasing. (Works for both sorted and non-sorted input.)

```py
def f(A, B):
  m = [[(float('inf'), -1) for b in B] for a in A]

  for i in xrange(len(A)):
    for j in xrange(i, len(B) - len(A) + i + 1):
      d = (A[i] - B[j]) ** 2

      if i == 0:
        if j == i:
          m[i][j] = (d, j)
        elif d < m[i][j-1][0]:
          m[i][j] = (d, j)
        else:
          m[i][j] = m[i][j-1]
      # i > 0
      else:
        candidate = d + m[i-1][j-1][0]
        if j == i:
          m[i][j] = (candidate, j)
        else:
          if candidate < m[i][j-1][0]:
            m[i][j] = (candidate, j)
          else:
            m[i][j] = m[i][j-1]

  result = m[len(A)-1][len(B)-1][0]
  # Backtrack
  lst = [None for a in A]
  j = len(B) - 1
  for i in xrange(len(A)-1, -1, -1):
    j = m[i][j][1]
    lst[i] = j
    j = j - 1
  return (result, [(A[i], B[j]) for i, j in enumerate(lst)])

A = [1, 2]
B = [0, 1, 10000]
print f(A, B)
print ""
A = [1.1, 2.3, 5.6, 5.7, 10.1]
B = [0, 1.9, 2.4, 2.7, 8.4, 9.1, 10.7, 11.8]
print f(A, B)
```

Output:

```
(2, [(1, 0), (2, 1)])

(16.709999999999997, [(1.1, 1.9), (2.3, 2.4), (5.6, 2.7), (5.7, 8.4), (10.1, 10.7)])
```

#### Update

Here's an `O(|B|)` space implementation. I'm not sure if this still offers a way to backtrack to get the mapping but I'm working on it.

```py
def f(A, B):
  m = [(float('inf'), -1) for b in B]
  m1 = [(float('inf'), -1) for b in B] # m[i-1]

  for i in xrange(len(A)):
    for j in xrange(i, len(B) - len(A) + i + 1):
      d = (A[i] - B[j]) ** 2

      if i == 0:
        if j == i:
          m[j] = (d, j)
        elif d < m[j-1][0]:
          m[j] = (d, j)
        else:
          m[j] = m[j-1]
      # i > 0
      else:
        candidate = d + m1[j-1][0]
        if j == i:
          m[j] = (candidate, j)
        else:
          if candidate < m[j-1][0]:
            m[j] = (candidate, j)
          else:
            m[j] = m[j-1]

    m1 = m
    m = m[:len(B) - len(A) + i + 1] + [(float('inf'), -1)] * (len(A) - i - 1)

  result = m1[len(B)-1][0]
  # Backtrack
  # This doesn't work as is
  # to get the mapping
  lst = [None for a in A]
  j = len(B) - 1
  for i in xrange(len(A)-1, -1, -1):
    j = m1[j][1]
    lst[i] = j
    j = j - 1
  return (result, [(A[i], B[j]) for i, j in enumerate(lst)])

A = [1, 2]
B = [0, 1, 10000]
print f(A, B)
print ""
A = [1.1, 2.3, 5.6, 5.7, 10.1]
B = [0, 1.9, 2.4, 2.7, 8.4, 9.1, 10.7, 11.8]
print f(A, B)

import random
import time

A = [random.uniform(0, 10000.5) for i in xrange(10000)]
B = [random.uniform(0, 10000.5) for i in xrange(15000)]

start = time.time()
print f(A, B)[0]
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: This looks very interesting. I will try it out as soon as possible.

Comment: I added another bottom up approach that used greedy to try to avoid as much work as possible in DP.

Comment: Does section 7 of http://cs.au.dk/~cstorm/students/MyHoa_Dec2010.pdf help?