# how to align similar values in two arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, timestamp, utc

I am trying to align two videos using their utc timestamps.

for example:

video 1 timestamps = `1234.4321, 1234.4731, 1234.5432, 1234.5638, ...`

video 2 timestamps = `1234.4843, 1234.5001, 1234.5632, 1234.5992, ...`

I would like to align them so that the closest timestamps within a .0150s window are aligned without aligning two values from one array to one value in the second array.

example output:

video 1 timestamps = `1234.4321, 1234.4731, _________, 1234.5432, 1234.5638, _________, ...`

video 2 timestamps = `_________, 1234.4843, 1234.5001, _________, 1234.5632, 1234.5992, ...`

Can someone help?

**EDIT**

There was a little confusion with the timestamps. The issue isn't that they simply need to be shifted once every two values. Hopefully this updated example will clear it up. Both examples are correct. **A single solution should be able to solve both.**

Example 2:

`timestamp3 = 1590595834.6775, 1590595834.70479, 1590595834.73812, 1590595834.77163, 1590595834.80438`

`timestamp4 = 1590595835.70971, 1590595835.73674, 1590595835.7695, 1590595835.80338, 1590595835.83634`

output:

`timestamp3 = 1590595835.6775, 1590595835.70479, 1590595835.73812, 1590595835.77163, 1590595835.80438, _______________, ...`

`timestamp4 = _______________, 1590595835.70971, 1590595835.73674, 1590595835.7695, 1590595835.80338, 1590595835.83634, ...`

Comment: Might be relevant for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171654/how-to-align-two-lists-of-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
timestamp3 = [1590595834.6775, 1590595834.70479, 1590595834.73812, 1590595834.77163, 1590595834.80438]
timestamp4 = [1590595834.70971, 1590595834.73674, 1590595834.7695, 1590595834.80338, 1590595834.83634]

len3 = len(timestamp3)
len4 = len(timestamp4)
ins = '_____________'
diff = 0.015
ii = jj = 0
while True:
    if timestamp3[ii] < timestamp4[jj] - diff:
        timestamp4.insert(jj, ins)
        len4 += 1
    elif timestamp4[ii] < timestamp3[jj] - diff:
        timestamp3.insert(ii, ins)
        len3 += 1

    ii += 1
    jj += 1
    if ii == len3 or jj == len4:
        if len3 > len4:
            timestamp4.extend([ins]*(len3-len4))
        elif len4 > len3:
            timestamp3.extend([ins]*(len4-len3))
        break

print(timestamp3)
print(timestamp4)
```

Gives:

```
[1590595834.6775, 1590595834.70479, 1590595834.73812, 1590595834.77163, 1590595834.80438, '_____________']
['_____________', 1590595834.70971, 1590595834.73674, 1590595834.7695, 1590595834.80338, 1590595834.83634]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

```
timestamps1 = [1234.4321, 1234.4731, 1234.5432, 1234.5638]
timestamps2 = [1234.4843, 1234.5001, 1234.5632, 1234.5992]

index = len(timestamps1)

while index > 0:
    timestamps1.insert(index,'_______')
    index -= 2
    timestamps2.insert(index,'_______')

print(timestamps1)
print(timestamps2)
```

Output:

```
[1234.4321, 1234.4731, '_______', 1234.5432, 1234.5638, '_______']
['_______', 1234.4843, 1234.5001, '_______', 1234.5632, 1234.5992]
```

Comment: hm not exactly. This just places '________' after every two values. Maybe I shouldn't have made the example this way. I meant that the numbers themselves need to be the aligning factor, not their place in line

Comment: So you want to shift the arrays to align?

Comment: Sort of. The values that don't align with a free value in the second array within +/- .0150s should be shifted and aligned with a '_____'. I updated the original post to clear it up hopefully. thanks for your help

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help you with that. Should I remove my post?