# Minimum Sum of Absolute Differences between Two Arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic

Say we are given two integer arrays A and B (both sorted in ascending order) with *m* and *n* elements respectively (such that *n>=m*). We have to pair each element of array A with a unique element in array B such that the sum of absolute differences (*ie. abs diff. b/w integers of a pair*) of all the pairs is minimum. Print the optimal pairs combination and the minimum sum from the same.

*For e.g.:*

```
A = [-95, -69, -29, -19]

B = [-125, -119, -94, -24, 181]

The optimal pair combination = [(-95, -119), (-69, -94), (-29,-24), (-19, 181)]
which gives the minimum sum of (24 + 25 + 5 + 200) = 254
```

We have to write a function which takes the two arrays A,B as well as their sizes as inputs and return the optimal pair combination array and minimum sum.

Comment: please show the code you have attempted

Comment: The algorithm I thought of was:
For each element in array A, find the least distant element in array B from it and then mark it as visited. And then continue the same for remaining elements of A and non-visited elements of B. This is obviously wrong because say:  A = [-100, 1000] and B=[-99, -1001]. By using this we get optimal solution (WRONG) as [(-100,-99) , (1000,-1001)] and sum as 2002. As you can see if we take pairs [(-100,-1001) , (-99,1000)] we get 2000 which is in case the optimal solution. 
I can't think of any other approach for this at the moment.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have attempted

Comment: Respectfully @Mathix420, this question was asked in my qualifying coding round for Infosys which I attempted today morning. I got struck in this question for more than an hour and a half and still could not find even a right thinking approach for the same. After my exam was complete, I gave it nearly 5-6 hours but still no luck.

Comment: My first attempt was not succesfull, if complexity is not an issue. You simply have to compute each possibilities and then get the lowest ones.

Comment: @Mathix420 The complexity will be a major issue since the array size can vary in wide range. Computing all possible pairs will for every integer in A will result in nCm factorial time complexity so there is need for some better approach. Also if its possible please reinstate your deleted answer because it will be very very helpful for others.

Comment: Your example seems wrong. The optimal solution is 150, not 254. `((-95) - (-125)) + ((-69) - (-119)) + ((-29) - (-94)) + ((-19) - (-24))`

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171654/how-to-align-two-lists-of-numbers). The cost is different but I believe the cost functions there can be replaced with this one.