# Shortest time for everyone to get to the destination

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I have to design an algorithm to solve a problem：
We have two groups of people (group A and group B, the number of people in group A is always less or equal to the number of people in group B）, all standing in a one-dimensional line, each people have a corresponding number indicating its location. When the timer starts, each people in group A must find a partner in group B, but people in group B cannot move at all and each people in group B can only have at most 1 partner.

Suppose that people in group A move 1 unit/sec, how can I find the minimum time for everyone in group A to find a partner？

for example, if there are three people in group A with location {5,7,8}, and four people in group B with location {2,3,4,9}, the optimal solution would be 3 sec because max(5-3,7-4,9-8)=3

I could just use brute-force to solve it, but is there a better way of solving this problem？

Comment: I think your question may be reduced to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171654/how-to-align-two-lists-of-numbers), which has an accepted `O(n)` answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a special case of the [edit distance problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance), and so a similar Dynamic Programming solution can be used to solve it. It's possible that a faster solution exists for this special case.

Let `A = [a_0, a_1...,a_(m-1)]` be the (sorted) positions of our `m` moving people, and `B = [b_0, b_1...,b_(n-1)]` be the `n` (sorted) destination spots, with `m <= n`. For the edit distance analogy, the allowed operations are:

1. Insert a number into `A` (free), or
2. Substitute an element `a -> a'` in `A` with cost `|a-a'|`.

We can solve this in `O(n*m)` time (plus sorting time of both `A` and `B`, if necessary).

We can define the dynamic programming via a cost function `C(i, j)` which is the minimum cost to move the first `i` people `a_0, ... a_(i-1)` using only the first `j` spots `b_0, ... b_(j-1)`. You want `C(m,n)`. Define `C` as follows:

[image: Equation]

Comment: Can't this problem be reduced to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171654/how-to-align-two-lists-of-numbers), which apparently has an `O(n)` solution (answer there)?

Comment: (Clearly we preserve order because crossing elements of A with each other would needlessly increase the cost.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן My initial reaction is that this problem should be reducible; going from the `sum of squared distances` metric to the `max distance` metric here may be a problem, but I can't tell which properties of the metric are being used to prove that solution's correctness. That is a very fascinating and surprising solution, though, so it will take me some time to study it to understand how and why it works.

Comment: I don't think the distance function makes a difference there. It's also easy to swap the distance function in their code and test against a DP with robust random input.

Comment: @גלעדברקן You're right; large scale random testing shows that their code produces seemingly identical answers to my dynamic programming solution. It also definitely appears to be `O(n)`; that said, I still have no idea why it works, but the code and the algorithm are written very clearly. It shouldn't be impossible to work out a proof given some time to think about it; btilly also gave a rough proof sketch in several places.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Short update: I made a mistake yesterday; in fact the linear time solution from the other problem does not appear to work. There were 3 full-length code snippets posted in that thread by the other user; 2 linear time solutions in one answer (one of which was incorrect), and a 'greedy-based' quadratic solution in another answer. I accidentally copied and tested the quadratic solution, which does work well. Unfortunately, the updated/corrected linear solution, while usually right, does fail on some rare inputs for this problem. I'm trying to see if a fix is possible.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks for the update. btilly might want to know, if you didn't advise them.

Comment: Which quadratic solution there worked well for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237726/discussion-between-kcsquared-and--).